# int 13h return 0x0C80

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev, real-mode

Recently I've been learning about operating systems, and currently I'm on the point of reading sectors with 13h/0x02. But when I run my code, I get the following error: 

`Disk read error! 0x0C80`

But the problem is vague, and when I look  it up it says timeout or media type not found (floppy).
Heres the relevant code:

**boot.asm**

```assembly
[org 0x7c00] ; bootloader offset
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl    

    mov bp, 0x9000 ; set the stack
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE
    call printf ; This will be written after the BIOS messages

    call load_kernel

    call switch_to_pm
    jmp $ ; this will actually never be executed

%include "/boot/printf.asm"
%include "/boot/diskload.asm"
%include "/boot/printhex.asm"
%include "/32bit-functions/gdt.asm"
%include "/32bit-functions/32bit-print.asm"
%include "/32bit-functions/switch.asm"

[bits 16]

load_kernel:
    mov bx, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL
    call printf

    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    mov dh, 0x01
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    call diskload

    ret

[bits 32]
BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE
    call print_string_pm

    call KERNEL_OFFSET ; Give control to the kernel
    jmp $ ; Stay here when the kernel returns control to us (if ever)

BOOT_DRIVE db 0 ; It is a good idea to store it in memory because 'dl' may get
                   ;overwritten
MSG_REAL_MODE db "Started in 16-bit Real Mode", 0
MSG_PROT_MODE db "Landed in 32-bit Protected Mode", 0
MSG_LOAD_KERNEL db "Loading kernel into memory", 0

; bootsector
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

**diskload.asm**

```assembly
; load 'dh' sectors from drive 'dl' into ES:BX
diskload:
    pusha
    ; reading from disk requires setting specific values in all registers
    ; so we will overwrite our input parameters from 'dx'. Let's save it
    ; to the stack for later use.
    push dx

    mov ch, 0x00 ; ch <- cylinder (0x0 .. 0x3FF, upper 2 bits in 'cl')
    ; dl <- drive number. Our caller sets it as a parameter and gets it from BIOS
    ; (0 = floppy, 1 = floppy2, 0x80 = hdd, 0x81 = hdd2)
    mov cl, 0x02 ; cl <- sector (0x01 .. 0x11)
    mov ah, 0x02 ; ah <- int 0x13 function. 0x02 = 'read'
    mov al, dh   ; al <- number of sectors to read (0x01 .. 0x80)
                 ; 0x01 is our boot sector, 0x02 is the first 'available' sector
    mov dh, 0x00 ; dh <- head number (0x0 .. 0xF)

    mov es, bx

    ; [es:bx] <- pointer to buffer where the data will be stored
    ; caller sets it up for us, and it is actually the standard location for int 13h
    int 0x13      ; BIOS interrupt
    jc disk_error ; if error (stored in the carry bit)

    pop dx
    cmp al, dh    ; BIOS also sets 'al' to the # of sectors read. Compare it.
    jne sectors_error
    popa
    ret


disk_error:
    mov bx, DISK_ERROR
    call printf
    call print_nl
    mov dh, ah ; ah = error code, dl = disk drive that dropped the error
    call printhex ; check out the code at http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_13-1.html
    jmp disk_loop

sectors_error:
    mov bx, SECTORS_ERROR
    call printf

disk_loop:
    jmp $


DISK_ERROR: db "Disk read error", 0
SECTORS_ERROR: db "Incorrect number of sectors read", 0
```

Im not quite sure what I've done wrong. And I did spend a while searching for an answer

[CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKHpQ.png)

Comment: `mov es, bx` looks wrong. _BX_ is the offset, you aren't suppose to copy it to _ES_. If you are trying to load to 0x0000:0x1000 then you should be setting _ES_ to zero and _BX_ to the offset 0x1000. As well you should be setting _SS:SP_ so you don't clobber the stack when loading from disk by setting it to something that won't interfere. You set _SP_ to 0x9000 but don't set _SS_ (I assume you intend _SS_ to be zero) You should also be setting _DS_ to zero (since you use an ORG of 0x7c00) before you copy _DL_ to BOOT_DRIVE